# Making a Rest Api to serve responsively for browsers and mobile apps

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, nosql

I want to dig in to restful services and Spring . And I want to make a restful api for my startup idea .This api should be serving for  both browsers and mobile apps. I do not know where to start .
 For example What should ı use at db level. A nosql approach or classical relational db approach? 
I appreciate if you guys can give me a clue about how to start this.

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Turkmen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know your idea. Decision of what technologies you should use is yours.

Building Rest service with Spring is very easy. The following tutorial is very good.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I advice you to start with something simple. Create a simple app to understand how Spring and other technologies work and then try to create your idea.

Good luck with startup :)

Comment: Thank you  for the answer. I already finished those tutorials. I think I should start designing and coding anyway :) We will see whats gonna happen and what mistakes I will make during development.